# Edit a class element using a method in C#

Tags: c#

```
class Person
{
    public int age;
    public string haircolor;
    public string name;
}

class Program
{
    static void skapaPerson(string name, string haircolor, int age) {
    Console.Write("Vad är personens namn? ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Hur gammal är personen?");
    age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Vad är personens hårfärg? ");
    haircolor = Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person Person1 = new Person();
    skapaPerson(Person1.name, Person1.haircolor, Person1.age);
    Console.Write("{0} {1} {2}", Person1.name, Person1.haircolor, Person1.age);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What I'm looking for is how to assign the values of the different class elements using the method, making me able to edit a specific element at any given time.

The write at the end was just for testing and at the current moment the write just returns "0" for me.

If able I would also like to know how to create new class elements using another method.

Comment: Pass in the `Person` object instead of the name, hair color and age separately.  And I suggest you read Jon Skeet's post about [parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of explicitly passing in each individual property, consider passing in the actual `Person` object to your method and setting the properties within your method :

```
static void skapaPerson(Person p) {
    Console.Write("Vad är personens namn? ");
    p.name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Hur gammal är personen?");
    p.age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Vad är personens hårfärg? ");
    p.haircolor = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

along with :

```
// Create an instance of your person
Person Person1 = new Person();
// Set it's properties
skapaPerson(Person1);
```

You can [see an interactive example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GszkXi).

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I didn't think of that myself.

Answer (score 3):

your class should look like this

```
static Person skapaPerson()
{
    Person pResult = new Person(); //create new Person object here
    Console.Write("Vad är personens namn? ");
    pResult.name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Hur gammal är personen?");
    pResult.age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Vad är personens hårfärg? ");
    pResult.haircolor = Console.ReadLine();
    return pResult; //return object with entered data
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person Person1 = skapaPerson(); //Person 1 is the result of skapaPerson()
    Console.Write("{0} {1} {2}", Person1.name, Person1.haircolor, Person1.age);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

if you want to gather data within your `skapaPerson` method you can create a `Person` object in there and return it